# How to set style of image with html5?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create image using HTML5, With HTML5 I can set any property of image.

```
var img = new Image()
img.id="image1"
img.name
img.src="image1.jpg"
img.style="-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)"
```

the result will become

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="image" name="asdasd">
```

all will work except style because I hope the result will be

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="image" name="asdasd" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);">
```

please help me, thx

Comment: Too less information provided, explain it in a better way

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML5?

Comment: you can also set the class or classes for predefined css (better) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be:

```
img.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotate(90deg)';
```

([see this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style))

Answer (score 2):

You can set the cssText field like so

```
var img = new Image()
img.id="image1"
img.src="image1.jpg"

img.style.cssText = '-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)'
```

Then when you evaluate the markup for the element, it will display

`<img id="image1" src="image1.jpg" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);">`